# Scanf only works alternately

Tags: c, gcc

I am facing a problem with the code below. As the output shows, after calling `scanf("%c", &choice);` the first time, `scanf` seems to stop working for next iteration and the `default` case is executing. However after that scanf works fine one more time and then doesn't work the next time. This cycle goes on. I am not able to understand the issue. What is the reason?

**Code:**

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    int value;
    node *root = NULL;
    printf("\tA. add node\n\tB. inorder\n\tC. pre order\n");
    printf("\tD. delete node\n\tE. post order\n\tF. Ascending\n");
    printf("\tD. Descending\n");
    do {
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 'A':
                printf("Enter value\n");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                addnode(&root, value);
                break;

            case 'B':
                inorder(root);
                break;

            case 'C':
                preorder(root);
                break;

            case 'D':
                printf("Enter value\n");
                scanf("%d", &value);
                deletenode(&root, value);
                break;

            case 'E':
                postorder(root);
                break;

            case 'F':
                ascending(root);
                break;

            case 'G':
                descending(root);
                break;

            case 'X':
                printf("Good Bye\n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("Enter proper choice\n");
                break;
        }
    } while(choice != 'X');
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
        A. add node
        B. inorder
        C. pre order
        D. delete node
        E. post order
        F. Ascending
        D. Descending
Enter your choice
A
Enter value
2
Enter your choice
Enter proper choice
Enter your choice
A
Enter value
4
Enter your choice
Enter proper choice
Enter your choice
D
Enter value
4
Enter your choice
Enter proper choice
Enter your choice
.
.
.
```

Comment: numerous dupes of this one. don't use `scanf()`. use `fgets()` and parse the input after reading.

Comment: @ameyCU no, just don't. that only suppresses the symptom, it doesn't cure the disease.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes , sorry :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip leading whitespace (previous newline) when reading the choice. Just add a space before `%c` in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```